# Magnitude-squared coherence using pwelch function yields different results than mscohere

Tags: matlab, coherence

I am trying to reproduce [mscohere](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/mscohere.html) function from Matlab.

$$C_{xy}(f) = \frac{\left\lvert P_{xy}(f)\right\rvert^2}{P_{xx}(f)P_{yy}(f)}$$

This is inside Algorithm section in docs for [mscohere](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/mscohere.html):

> mscohere estimates the magnitude-squared coherence function using Welch’s overlapped averaged periodogram method.

So I was thinking, this should get the same results:

```
Fs = 1000;

%signal definition
t = 0 : 1/Fs : 1-1/Fs;
x = cos(2*pi*100*t) ...
  + sin(2*pi*200*t) ...
  + 0.5*randn(size(t));
y = 0.5*cos(2*pi*100*t - pi/4) ...
  + 0.35*sin(2*pi*200*t - pi/2) ...
  + 0.5*randn(size(t));

%params for pwelch and mscohere
window = hamming(100);
noverlap = 80;
nfft = 100;

%coherence computation
pwelch_Corr = pwelch(xcorr(x,y,'normalized'), window, noverlap, nfft);
pwelch_x = pwelch(x, window, noverlap, nfft);
pwelch_y = pwelch(y, window, noverlap, nfft);

coherence_welch = (abs(pwelch_Corr).^2) ./ (pwelch_x.*pwelch_y);
coherence_mscohere = mscohere(x, y, window, noverlap, nfft);

%display
subplot 211;
plot(coherence_welch);
title('using pwelch and xcorr');

subplot 212;
plot(coherence_mscohere);
title('using mscohere');
```

But no:

[image]

In this case, it is a lot similar. But with my real-world signals it's much more different.

What am I doing wrong? **How to reproduce `mscohere` behavior?**

(The reason why I want this is rewriting code in C# and matlab functions are considered as a golden standard for that)

Comment: Hm, does looking at `toolbox/signal/signal/mscohere.m` in your matlab installation help? Seems they're just calling `welch({x,y}, 'mscohere', inputArgs{:})`, and `private/welch.m` tells us (line 204ff) how the `'mscohere'` case is implemented.

Comment: Well, that is a trick I have to say. I was stopped inside mscohere.m file when I saw implementation is somewhere else... Surprisingly enough when `cpsd` is used instead of a `pwelch(xcorr..)` it works the same. Now the question shifts to `what type of correlation is used in welch.m file`. I wasn't able to see that difference in that source code..

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is in your numerator you are performing the Welch’s power spectral density estimate on the cross correlation of x and y. Instead you should perform the Cross power spectral density between x and y. See your updated code below. I have replace 1 line of your code and now I'm getting the same result on both images.

Also keep in mind that in MATLAB doing `cpsd(x,x)` should be equivalent to `pwelch(x)`.

```
Fs = 1000;

%signal definition
t = 0 : 1/Fs : 1-1/Fs;
x = cos(2*pi*100*t) ...
  + sin(2*pi*200*t) ...
  + 0.5*randn(size(t));
y = 0.5*cos(2*pi*100*t - pi/4) ...
  + 0.35*sin(2*pi*200*t - pi/2) ...
  + 0.5*randn(size(t));

%params for pwelch and mscohere
window = hamming(100);
noverlap = 80;
nfft = 100;

%coherence computation
%pwelch_Corr = pwelch(xcorr(x,y,'normalized'), window, noverlap, nfft);
pwelch_Corr = cpsd(x,y,window, noverlap, nfft);
pwelch_x = pwelch(x, window, noverlap, nfft);
pwelch_y = pwelch(y, window, noverlap, nfft);

coherence_welch = (abs(pwelch_Corr).^2) ./ (pwelch_x.*pwelch_y);
coherence_mscohere = mscohere(x, y, window, noverlap, nfft);

%display
subplot 211;
plot(coherence_welch);
title('using pwelch and cpsd');

subplot 212;
plot(coherence_mscohere);
title('using mscohere');
```

[image]